# How do I add params and Cookie to http post java request?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to invoke a webservice method which takes 2 input parameters and also needs a cookie to authenticate.

```
        PostMethod method = new PostMethod("webservice EP URL");
        NameValuePair code = new NameValuePair("Code", "");
        NameValuePair revision = new NameValuePair("Rev", "Latest");

        NameValuePair targetUri = new NameValuePair("TARGET", "GetObject");
        method.setRequestBody(new NameValuePair[] { code, revision,targetUri});
        int statusNew = client.executeMethod(method);
```

I dont know how to achieve it. Above code is what i am doing currently.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I dont know how to pass the cookie to this call. I want to pass SMSession cookie to this call. Also, I want to know how to pass input parameters to a webservice method.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? What type of web service you are trying to invoke (REST/SOAP)?

Comment: I am accessing SOAP webservice. I know how to do it for Rest Service using Jersey. But not sure about soap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the SOAP Handler, we can pass the headers in the request and it will do the job.

```
GetObject_Service_Impl impl = new GetObject_Service_Impl();
        // Get Iterator for all service ports
        Iterator iter = impl.getPorts();

        // Now create a new List of HandlerInfo objects - only one really.
        // Our client handler
        List handlerChain = new ArrayList();
        handlerChain.add(new HandlerInfo(SoapHandler.class, null, null));

        // Get Handler Registry
        HandlerRegistry registry = impl.getHandlerRegistry();
        // Register each port with the handler
        while (iter.hasNext())
            registry.setHandlerChain((QName) iter.next(), handlerChain);
```

And Write a new class say SoapHandler.java as below

public class SoapHandler extends GenericHandler {

```
HandlerInfo hi;

public void init(HandlerInfo info) {
    hi = info;
}

public QName[] getHeaders() {
    return hi.getHeaders();
}

public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext context) {

    return true;
}

/**
 * This method is use to add custom headers to existing SAOP request
 */
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) {
    System.out.println("response");

    try {
        SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        MimeHeaders hd = message.getMimeHeaders();
        hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic some credentials");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new JAXRPCException(e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

And thats it.....its ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are dealing with RESTful web services (Just my guess as you are passing parameters as http form params). Here is how to pass cookies

```
method.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "special-cookie=value");
```

Here just change `"special-cookie=value"` to your specific cookie that you are trying to pass.

EDIT: **Adding cookie to SOAP request**:

The quickest way to do is as follows

(Assuming that the `call` object you are using is an instance of `org.apache.axis.client.Call`)

```
call.setProperty(
        org.apache.axis.client.Call.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, 
        new Boolean(true));
    call.setProperty(
        org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_COOKIE2, 
        "\r\nCookieName=" + "CookieValue");
```

Please check *"Use a SOAPAction HTTP Header"* topic on [this](http://www.nsftools.com/stubby/ApacheAxisClientTips.htm) link.

Comment: I need to access SOAP Webservice.

Comment: A SOAP services works differently from REST. It exposes a service contact call [WSDL](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/default.asp). Please check out the this part. Then you need to [generate web services client](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) from this WSDL

Comment: Atleast someone please tell me how to add cookie here 
Service service = new Service();
call call = (Call) service.createCall();

Comment: @Afroz, I have updated my answer with the additional code example.

Comment: Service service = new Service();
   Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
   call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, new Boolean(true));
   call.setProperty("\r\nUSER:", "myid");
   call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_COOKIE2, "\r\nCookie:" + value);

Comment: Weird, just try removing the ':' and putting '=' between name and value. Also please try check how are these being passed in a http request using some tool.

Comment: I have introduced a SAOP Handler class to intercept the SAOP request and and passed user credentials as headers. And it worked.